# Como editar Item de listview?

Tags: java, xml

Estoy llamando mi lista y me muestra la lista de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero ajustar cada Ítem colocando a cada uno su background, botón y datos que obtengo así debería de quedar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia

[image: Anexo el código donde obtengo mi lista]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para hacer ese tipo de cosas debes de crear un adaptador personalizado, creando un XML con la vista como tal, y un adaptador que "infle" dicha vista.
Para no hacerla tan larga, te dejo unos links que podrian ayudarte:

https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd

https://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/